# Django translation in template: trans works "trans as" not

Tags: django, translation

I'm new to django and try the translation feature in views. I came across following problem:

I tried to translate a text into a variable, but this is always empty. However if I just output it works fine.

```
{% extends "myownapp/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% trans "Test" as test %}   <--- here it is defined 

{% block title %}Title - {% trans "Test" %}{% endblock %} <--- does work

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ test }}</h1>   <--- does not work
{% endblock %}
```

Note: I haven't created the language files yet - could this be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `{% trans "Test" as test %}` into the template block in which you are using the variable:

```
{% block content %}
    {% trans "Test" as test %}
    <h1>{{ test }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```